# Regular expression for split by commas but skip commas inside "<" ">"

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
String string = "contentType:string,header:string,alternativeIds:array<string>";
```

I want to split this String by "," but not get inside the brackets "<>", so in the example above the result that I get is good just by splitting with by ",":

```
 contectType:string
 header:string,
 alternativeIds:array<string>
```

but when I added more commas inside the "< >" expression, my regex doesn't work.

```
String string = "contentType:string,header:string,alternativeIds:array<struct<id:int,name:string>>, flag:boolean";
```

I am expected to:

```
contectType:string
header:string
array<struct<id:int,name:string>>
flag:boolean
```

And the struct can be more and more nested, I just want to split by commas without handling the "<>" cases.
This is the regex that I tried:

```
String regex = ",(?![^<>]*\\))"
```

But it still takes the commas inside.

Comment: This is not a good application of regex. You should parse the string with regular code. Morever, without knowing the programming language and regex library you are using, it is impossible even to come up with a guess.

Answer (score 0):

**In your case this regex should work:**

```
,(?![\w:]*>)
```

**The explanation**:

Match any ',' that doesn't have in front [\w:]* any number of alphanumeric characters and other symbols (in your case I could only see ':', but you should add any other character that can occur inside the square brackets) followed by a '>'. If the ',' does have a '>', it must mean that it is between the '<>'.

Only combination of characters you shouldn't input inside the square brackets are the '<' and ',' itself.